# Counting, dedupping and trending an export

Tags: excel

I've got a csv export of single col of date submissions and im trying to figure out the total count for each day I.E if 10 submissions on 15/7/2020, that will be 10 rows. Ideally trying to count dates, dedupe dates and add count to each date so i can trend in a graph

I have no idea where to start and wondering if anyone would be kind enough to help. Don't get me wrong i've googled and searched a fair bit but no cookie cutter approach that i could find - maybe im searching for the wrong answer though

[image]

Big thanks!
Chris~

Comment: To count these dates and dedupe them, I'd opt for an Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a graph you want, go on Insert > Pivot Chart and select the relevant source data on the sheet (should select it automatically). Then in the Fields editor on the right, drag your date series into 'Axis (categories)' and then into 'Values'. It might automatically add sub-categories for months, quarters or years - you can use or delete them from the field editor as you wish.
"So I can trend in a graph" - guessing this means a line graph of some kind, I think it will default to a column graph but you can change chart type by right-clicking on the chart, or in the 'design' tab.

Comment: By skipping straight to the graph stage like this, it should hopefully remove the need to do counting and deduping and things. However if you still need all that, it's totally possible - but that would be for a different answer...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any idea if it will work if my dates are really time stamps that ive changed to a short date?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OI8euYj-Qlv5twSfWwYvJ5xb4EWNZozY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @chris that depends on a few things, but I'd have thought it would be manageable - give it a try. (Those automatic sub-categories I mentioned, probably include one for just date).

Comment: Hmmm i can only get month... trying to get day. If you have any ideas that would be awesome. Cheers

Comment: @chris in the field editor look in 'Axis (categories)' - are there two lines in the box? If there's one for month and another for date, drag the month one out - either to the 'filter' section or just out of the box completely. Then let me know if it changes.

Comment: Hey Spencer, thanks for the reply. I have a feeling im not doing something correctly. Here's what i see: https://imgur.com/a/oQxup98

Comment: forgot to add the count col in the earlier pic, but strange no date option